# TargetException in RealProxy Invoke Message for generic type call in a method group

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, proxy, remoting

Let's say I have an generic interface  `IService<T>` and a class implementing it `Service : IService<Bar>`
I create a proxy of that interface :

```
var proxy = new DynamicProxy<IService<Bar>>(new Service()).GetTransparentProxy() as IService<Bar>;
```

DynamicProxy is a simple implementation of RealProxy :

```
    public class DynamicProxy<I> : RealProxy
    {
        private I _decorated;

        public DynamicProxy(I decorated) : base(typeof(I))
        {
            this._decorated = decorated;
        }

        public override IMessage Invoke(IMessage msg)
        {
            IMethodCallMessage methodCall = (IMethodCallMessage)msg;
            MethodInfo methodInfo = methodCall.MethodBase as MethodInfo;

            return new ReturnMessage(
                methodInfo.Invoke(this._decorated, methodCall.InArgs),
                null,
                0,
                methodCall.LogicalCallContext,
                methodCall);
        }
    }
```

When using my proxy directly it works fine :

```
IEnumerable<Bar> bars = new List<Bar>() { new Bar { id = 2 }, new Bar { id = 3 } };
proxy.Foo(bars.First());
```

or even with a lambda, it's fine :

```
 var data = bars.ToList().Select(bar => proxy.Foo(bar)).ToList();
```

But when used with a method group, it throws a target exception

```
var data = bars.ToList().Select(proxy.Foo).ToList();
```

The thrown exception :

```
{System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
```

It seems that the realproxy doesn't manage to get the correct type of the generic :

The MethodBase of the IMethodCallMessage is `{Int32 Foo(System.__Canon)}` instead of `{Int32 Foo(Bar)}`

Is it a limitation of the method group? or a bug in the RealProxy implementation?

You can see it here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/w2VlVN

No luck in the [MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0cf6e64d-d2a9-421e-8b4b-25a222adce7c/targetexception-with-realproxy-when-invoked-by-a-method-group-on-a-generic-interface-but-works-with?forum=netfxbcl), How can I open a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is here:

```
methodInfo.Invoke(this._decorated, methodCall.InArgs),
```

The `this` argument is wrong here, you need to invoke your class directly rather then using `this`.

Try pass `_decorated` directly without using `this`.

Comment: This doesn't change anything. `this._decorated` or `_decorated` is the same object...